# How to update combobox height according to textstyle change

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a Combobox in my wpf application. The user can change its text style in runtime. When text font becomes larger, the bottom half of the text is covered like this [Combobox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uV0Nb.jpg)

This is because the height of the Combobox is not updated. But if I update the height directly using this.combobox.Height=200, it becomes like this[Combobox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9uRX.jpg)

The question is how to update combobox.Height in run time and how to get the new height?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to dynamically update the height of your combo.
For that do a calculation of the new height value according the current font size and change it.

An example with Textbox here: [Set TextBox Height](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29140/Set-TextBox-Height)

A good solution would be to bind the Height with a calculated property in your context.